# Method for measuring the percentual of time span in a Differential Equation solver

Tags: python, scipy, julia, differentialequations.jl

I use Differential Equations from julia (previously solve_ivp from scipy) and it would be very convenient for me to have a notion of the amount of time steps that have occured.
For example, if my simulation has a timespan = (0.0, 10e4), the method should print each increase of 1% of the total timespan.
I thought about using a for loop inside the dydt function to print time at every interval but I'm afraid the amount of text printed will pollute too much my notebook output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to use a callback https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/features/callback_functions/ to print when appropriate. Note that since timestep size is dynamic, this spacing evenly over timesteps will not space evenly over time.